# SQL how to join two tables with same column names but different data in SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle

In need you help with that.

I have two databases with 42 column names and need merge to another database with the same 42 columns with the same column names but different values.

DT1

```
Column0 | Column1 | column3 | column… | column42
1234 example 345 final1
1234 example 567 final3
1234 example 789 final5
12345 example 7890 final9
12345 example 890 final10
```

DT2

```
Column0 | Column1 | column3 | column… | column42
4567 example 345 final1
4567 example 567 final3
4567 example 789 final5
45678 example 7890 final9
45678 example 890 final10
```

DT Result

```
Column0 | Column1 | column3 | column… | column42
1234 example 345 final1
1234 example 567 final3
1234 example 789 final5
12345 example 7890 final9
12345 example 890 final10
4567 example 345 final1
4567 example 567 final3
4567 example 789 final5
45678 example 7890 final9
45678 example 890 final10
```

Thanks!

my code

```
#directory where report results will be saved
report_result = r"path\report_result_%s.csv"%today
report_result_sql_query =""" Select b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, ... b.column42
,a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, ... a.column42
FROM table1 b
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 a
ON a.column1=b.column2
WHERE b.column2 like '%ff%'AND (a.column3 is null or a.column3= '0' or a.column3= ' ') AND a.column2 like '%ff%' AND b.column5 >= '{}' AND a.column5>= '{}'""".format(day,yyday)
print(report_result_sql_query)
report_result_colour = web_service(report_result_sql_query)
print(report_result_colour.shape)
ORC_genesis1_colour.to_csv(report_results_final, index=False)
```

It is not giving an error however it is giving zero rows and columns but when I run both tables in two separate SQL queries I get results so I assume something is wrong in my join

Comment: 'It is not giving an error' - MYSQL does not have FULL JOIN so either this statement is incorrect or you are not using mysql - mssql/sql-server maybe. Please check and correct tags

Comment: How are you trying to merge? Maybe a UNION makes more sense?

Comment: I am using sql in python not sure whether it have the same characteristics as mysql

Comment: @ahmad which database management systems (DBMS) are you querying from? Is there a way you could find out?

Comment: Publish the import..connector statement.

Comment: @StonedTensor DBMS is ORACLE

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT column0, column1, column3, column42
FROM   DT1
WHERE  column1 is null
OR     column1= '0'
OR     column1= 'example'
UNION ALL
SELECT column0, column1, column3, column42
FROM   DT2
WHERE  column42 like 'f%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE DT1 (Column0, Column1, column3, column42) AS
SELECT 1234,  'example', 345,  'final1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234,  'example', 567,  'final3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234,  'example', 789,  'final5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, 'example', 7890, 'final9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, 'example', 890,  'final10' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE DT2 (Column0, Column1, column3, column42) AS
SELECT 4567,  'example', 345,  'final1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4567,  'example', 567,  'final3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4567,  'example', 789,  'final5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45678, 'example', 7890, 'final9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45678, 'example', 890,  'final10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN42 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | example | 345 | final1 |
| 1234 | example | 567 | final3 |
| 1234 | example | 789 | final5 |
| 12345 | example | 7890 | final9 |
| 12345 | example | 890 | final10 |
| 4567 | example | 345 | final1 |
| 4567 | example | 567 | final3 |
| 4567 | example | 789 | final5 |
| 45678 | example | 7890 | final9 |
| 45678 | example | 890 | final10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zs1SiMUN)

Comment: still prints (0,0)

Comment: @ahmad I am not entirely sure what point you are trying to make when you post code with no accompanying text; however your code is not valid as `column3= ' 'tradeDate >= '{}'` is not valid syntax (it looks like you are missing an `AND` or an `OR`). Even if you fix that I am unable to comment on whether it is correct or not as you have not provided a [MRE] (with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and details of the expected output) that we can test against.

Comment: Hi the comment was posted accidentally was trying to go to an new line and posted it apologies the main code is in the question and the answer still prints (0,0)

Comment: @ahmad It works for me if the `WHERE` clauses actually match the data [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zs1SiMUN). (But if the `WHERE` clauses do not match any rows then, of course, it will not return anything; as per the last example in the fiddle.)

Comment: The where clause matches the data fiddle as if i run them in two separate queries and export them i will have about 200 rows for each but when i try to run both queries together i get (0,0).

Comment: @ahmad As already stated, I cannot help you further unless you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74428763/edit) to provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the queries that you are using. The query works in my fiddle with the data you have provided and it is impossible to replicate your output because I do not have your data or your exact queries.

Comment: The question is exactly what i am trying to do the code is excatly the same i am only hiding paths and column names but i am trying to export it to an excel and not have it run in 'idea' i am running it in python by connecting to oracle database so the syntax doesnt work unless you use """ before select and """ at the end of the argument

Comment: @ahmad Don't use template strings and string concatenation to build queries (as it leaves your vulnerable to SQL injection attacks). Use parameterised queries and bind variables (and if your web service does not support them then use a better API). You have not provided a proper [MRE] as you Python code is not complete and executable and your SQL code references columns that are undefined in your sample data... as stated in previous comments, you need to provide a [MRE] we can use to test the code.